# What can I change in a Solana program after deployment

Tags: solana-program, rust

Pretty much the title...I was always under the impression that once the program is deployed it is immutable, however I have recently seen companies changing the logic of their onchain programs after deployment. So my question is, for a deployed onchain program with the instruction/function `X` that takes parameters `Ps` and accounts `As`, what can I modify in `Ps` and `As` after deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can literally change anything and everything.

Until a program is *marked* as immutable (which is an irreversible operation), the upgrade authority can make any arbitrary changes to the bytes of the buffer account containing the program's byte-code. They can even point the program to an entirely different buffer account.

This is a significant risk vector and must be accounted for before interacting with any program on mainnet.

But there are operational reasons why this is generally preferable to non-upgradeable programs. As a developer, upgradeable programs allow one to:

- address bugs and vulnerabilities (this is kind of the big one)
- keep up to date with CPI'd programs that might have updated
- re-assign hard-coded accounts

This trust issue can be mitigated by a number of measures, including only interacting with programs:

- whose developers are not anonymous
- whose code is open-source
- whose upgrade authority is behind a multisig, preferably one where transaction proposals must execute after a delay, so that malicious changes can be noticed ahead of time.

Comment: Please mark it with a checkmark if you believe it adequately answers your question.